# PHP - Want to return the date of last Sunday in any given day

Tags: php

I want to create a "pic of the week" on my website and have it dynamically change from Sunday - Sunday. So once the next Sunday comes around, it changes to that day. Here's what I got so far:

```
function getLastSunday(){
if (1==1)
{
$today = date('F j Y');
$lastSunday = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('last Sunday', $today));
}
return $lastSunday;
}
```

It is returning "01/01/1970". I want it to return "10/13/2013" and next week I want it to return "10/20/2013"

Comment: What is the meaning of `if(1==1)`???

Comment: Drop the second argument to `strtotime()`.

Comment: @Emilio the meaning is `if (true)`. Seriously, don't you know Boolean logic? ;)

Comment: The function only worked if it was in an if statement otherwise I got an error. I'm new to PHP, is there another way to work around that if statement? Try / catch?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, because I know the boolean logic I'm asking why?

Comment: You should read the manual about [Control Structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string as the second argument to `strtotime()`, it really wants a number of seconds according to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Making that a time (or maybe even just ignoring it?) should make it work better:

```
function getLastSunday(){
if (1==1)
{
$today = date('F j Y');
$lastSunday = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('last Sunday', strtotime($today)));
}
return $lastSunday;
}
```

What you really want is this though I think:

```
function getLastSunday() {
    return date('m/d/Y', strtotime('last Sunday'));
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me the menaing of `if(1==1)`? already know what it's  mean..but why??

Comment: @EmilioGort I have no idea, I just copied OP's code. Best guess: there is some other convoluted if statement there in his real code and he replaced it because it has nothing to do with the question?

Comment: Beautiful, perfect, works. Thank you man. And I'm new to PHP - I put if(1==1) because if I didn't put the code inside an if statement, I would get an error - the page wouldn't even load. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: @GeorgeMcKenzie well that's weird, you definitely don't need an if statement. Maybe make sure you remove the ending `}` too?

Comment: @GeorgeMcKenzie Just updated with some better code, I say try that and report back if something doesn't work

Comment: new code works also - thank you